# Regex , get full string before specific sign or get full string if it don't contain the sign

Tags: regex

Is there any way to get all string (include other sign like -,)
before a given specific sign (in this case '@' sign)?

Example **domain\username@abc**
I want to get "**domain\username**" so I use expression **(.+)@** and it work.

but in same time there will be some input witch are without @abc only "domain\username" ,So it don't need to be split, (.+) will work

But can't figure out a regex expression that can match both ,

1. Domain\username@abc.com return **Domain\username**
2. Domain\username return **Domain\username**

**IN THE SAME GROUP**

My solution is make a if-else before regex expression so it can decide is string contains @ sign, so I can apply different expression for both situations.

I had tried

1. Use or (|) to make end of string are @ or word boundary :(.+)(@|\b) ->it always match \b so it will not stop at '@' sign
2. Make @ sign match 0 or 1 times  : (.+)@{0,1} ->>I don't understand Why this not work.But it not work in regex101.com ,it will always match full string

Comment: your 2. try match all, because of greedy Expression https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^[^@]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GTw6kI/2)

It will match one or more chars other than `@` (`[^@]+`) at the start of the string (`^`).

Comment: It work perfectly .
And then I make something different Like
https://regex101.com/r/g3dCpC/1 with new idea !